# Unity - Put different gameobject in function OntriggerEnter

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

My project is make a line between a target and a AGV.
apologize my english skill. My english is not good.

here are my code how it works.

1. find positions of target and AGV
2. get a simple linear equation by use of AGV's position x,y and target's position x,y
3. place dots on the simple linear equation which I just found in step 2.
4. when my dots meet a tag "wall" do something something... (not yet made)

so here is my problem:

[image]

[image]

my C# 'MapFile.cs' Script is installed on EmptyObject 'Map'.

When scene start, dots begin to place on the linear equation gradually AGV to target.
but i want stop placing dots when the last dot meet the 'wall' objects.

so tried to use function

```
void onTriggerEnter(Collider other)
```

but as you see, 'MapFile.cs' script is installed on EmptyObject 'Map'...

I have no idea how to my dots interaction with the walls.

here is my code

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using MLAgents;

public class MapFile : Agent
{
    public Transform targetPosition;
    public Transform AGVposition;

    public GameObject dot;

    public float w, b;

    public float functionTarget = 0f;

    public float[] data = new float[2];

    void Awake()
    {
        Initializing();
    }

    public void Initializing()
    {
        data[0] = AGVposition.position.x;
        data[1] = AGVposition.position.y;
    }

    public void drawline()
    {
        if(data[0] < 20f && data[0] > -20f)
        {
            while(true)
            {
                data[1] = FindYValue(data[0]); 
                Instantiate(dot, new Vector3( data[0] , 0f , data[1] ) , Quaternion.identity);

                if(targetPosition.position.x > 0 )
                {
                    data[0] += 0.07f;
                    if(data[0] > 20f) break;
                }
                else
                {
                    data[0] -= 0.07f;
                    if(data[0] < -20f)break;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    void Update()
    {         
        drawline();        
    }


    public float FindYValue(float a)
    {
        float result;

        float x1 = AGVposition.position.x;
        float y1 = AGVposition.position.z;
        float x2 = targetPosition.position.x;
        float y2 = targetPosition.position.z;

        result = ( (y2 - y1) / (x2 - x1) ) * (a - x1) + y1;

        return result;
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: I did not really understand everything, but you only want a line between two object, that does not pass through other object ? If so, simply shoot a raycast from object1 to object2, and set the endPosition of your lineRenderer to the end of the ray

Comment: I agree with Jichael, it isnt entirely clear what you wanted. However, these "dots" are gameobjects, you can on the dot have a script with ontriggeretner.. and if the thing it collides with has a tag of wall, do something.. so OnTriggerEnter(Collider thing) { if (thing.gameObject.tag=="Wall") DoSomething(); }

Comment: What about rather using a Raycast, take the distance between origin and hit position, divide it by the size of the dot and instantiate dots only between these two points?

Comment: Your wall probably doesn't have `isTrigger` checked. But derHugo and Jichael are correct, you should use a raycast for this.